# Where can I find a vent window for an 86 C10?

Tags: chevrolet, power-windows

I found brotherstrucks.com and they have the window, but only with a green tint.  The local auto-window shops have the glass for over 3x the cost. Amazon doesnt appear to carry windows. Anybody know where I can get vent glass window for $50.00 or less (the brothers price)?

Comment: See this [meta post](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/52/85) for more info, feedback on meta welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.lmctruck.com/icatalog/cc/full.aspx?Page=16c lmc truck parts has it listed for 39.95